# can templates with javascript work in haskell miso

Tags: haskell, haskell-miso

For DTL(Django template language), usually I find templates and just fill contents, everything will work. Now I am looking at elm and haskell miso. It seems that for elm, I have to handle javascript carefully, some may need to implement in elm.

What about haskell miso? I looked into some examples, it seems that if a template include javascript files, I can still include them in miso, just need to handle something like OnClick, etc.? Is it behave the same as in DTL?

Thanks.

Comment: In the one Miso app I’ve written, I didn’t need any JavaScript at all; where I might have written a “template” in an old-school framework, I’d write an ordinary Haskell function to generate the HTML for me.